# which task / program will consume lot of memory space of android device?

Tags: android, memory

I want to use memory or stress memory, at its peak capability consuming most of the RAM space. I came up with tasks like parallelly searching text in many files, calling functions recursively to fill stack space.

Comment: Fill the memory? `List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>(); while(true) {list.add(0l);}` and watch it fill.

Comment: @nikdange_me it depends on your device ram and heap space, differ for hardware

Answer (score 0):

Searching will not fill your memory on its own. To fill your heap you need to hold many or large objects in memory.

For example:

```
List<String> mList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < 999999; i++) {
  mList.add("Garbage");
}
```

Comment: Why not just while true, add?

Comment: It depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve. You need to find out how much heap you have and then figure out whether you want to fill up the entire heap to have your apk destroyed by the ActivityManager or whether you want to fill up your heap to say 80% to make the app extremely slow.

Comment: If you want the app to be killed for sure do while (true), otherwise use a specific number of objects with for.

Comment: But I'm saying there is no knowing that "magic number" without precomputing the available memory

Comment: You can find out by taking a heap dump, running the code to instantiate a bunch of objects and take another heap dump to get an idea.